# Randomly execute keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to create a Twitter bot that only sends out tweets periodically. I'm using the `random.choice` function to have it execute the tweets randomly. It's been running just fine since I created it, but now I'm trying to modify it by adding pictures to the tweets. Without pictures, I just need a simple list to put my tweets in, but I'm guessing a dictionary would be necessary if I want to add pictures.
Here's some sample code of how I've been trying to do this:

```
import random
import tweepy

dict = {"key1" : "KeyValue1.jpg", "Key2" : "KeyValue2.jpg", "Key3" : "KeyValue3.jpg"}

for d in dict:
    tweet = api.update_with_media(d, dict[d])
    print(tweet)
```

That's basically how it looks. Technically, that code works, but it only executes the first key and key value.
The `update_with_media` function requires 2 arguments, the first of which needs to be a jpg file, and the second one being the tweet itself.

Comment: first of dont use variable named `dict` as its a built-in name in python also im pretty sure you can store images in a list too

Comment: your dict is not consistent, for example the last item has it key as jpg while the 1st and 2nd items has the needed format to make successful iteration which match ur needs by jpg first and tweet second, so first first make a consistent dict items as tweet: jpg, then use my code below.

Comment: `update_with_media` is a deprecated function, FWIW - once you have figured out the dictionary key selection, I'd recommend using the media upload function and then the statuses update to post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 
import tweepy
        
d = {"key1" : "KeyValue1.jpg", "Key2" : "KeyValue2.jpg",  "KeyValue3": "Key3.jpg"} 
    
tweet = api.update_with_media(random.choice(list(d.keys())),random.choice(list(d.values()))) 
print(tweet)
```

Comment: you have to choose a key and image randomly not just post all at once

Comment: i checked it out

Comment: This is good! But would it be possible to make it where the keys and values still match each other? I don't want that part randomized. I like this code though!

Comment: you mean u wanna randomized dict items?

Answer (score 0):

to get a random item from dictionary:

```
import random

a = {'key1': 'sample', 'key2': 'sample2'}
b = random.choice([value for key, value in a.items()])
print(b)
```

although at this point might as well just use a list

Answer (score 0):

for randomized item or key, value pair follow this approach

```
import random
import tweepy

d = {"key1" : "KeyValue1.jpg", "Key2" : "KeyValue2.jpg",  "KeyValue3": "Key3.jpg"} 
  
res = key, val = random.choice(list(d.items())) 
tweet = api.update_with_media(str(res)) 
print(tweet)
```